# Is it possible to install docker-compose in sles 12?

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, suse

I want to install docker-compose in my SUSE Linux enterprise 12 system.

I found the correct package repository for docker service.

```
sudo zypper ar -t https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Virtualization:containers/SLE_12_SP3/Virtualization:containers.repo
zypper refresh
zypper install docker
```

I cant find anything about docker-compose, is it possible to install in SLES 12 SP3?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/ee/docker-ee/suse/

Comment: You also need package for docker-compose, it's not a standard in docker engine

Comment: @Jayr but this documentation is for install docker enterprise, no docker-compose

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should probably use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question. Also see [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/docker+install.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the documentaion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/), if you already have the prerequisite `python` and `pip` installed and you use the "alternative install solutions", this should be as easy as:

```
pip install docker-compose
```

Although it is not the default linux install in the doc, this is by far my preferred one.

If pip is not your option and you know which version you want to install, you can go with the "official" method for linux. (replace version 1.25.0 by yours)

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Comment: Neither zypper not pip installations worked for our servers (unsupported PyYAML version). 
Thank you for the "official" method. Finally I got docker-compose to be working